# To get the restricted ips for webapp in Azure powershell

Tags: azure-powershell

Is there any way to  get the restricted ips for the webapps in Azure using powershell cmdlets.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Comment: No that's fine.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function show all Azure WebApp IP restrictions in subscription for your reference.

```
function Get-WebAppIPRestrictions {

    if (!(Get-AzureRmContext)) {
        Write-Host "Please login to your Azure account"
        Login-AzureRmAccount
    }
    $APIVersion = ((Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Web).ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq sites).ApiVersions[0]
    $WebApps = Get-AzureRmWebApp
    foreach ($webApp in $WebApps) {

        $WebAppName = $WebApp.SiteName
        $WebAppRGName = $WEbApp.ResourceGroup
        $WebAppConfig = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName  $WebAppName -ResourceGroupName $WebAppRGName -ApiVersion $APIVersion)
        $IpSecurityRestrictions = $WebAppConfig.Properties.ipsecurityrestrictions
        if ($IpSecurityRestrictions -eq $null) {
            Write-Host "No IP restrictions found for WebApp $WebAppName ."

        }
        else {
            Write-Host "IP restrictions set for WebApp $WebAppName : "
            $IpSecurityRestrictions

        }
    }
}
```