# How to get the IP restriction for azure app service scm website or kudu console

Tags: azure-powershell

I am trying to get the all IP restriction for app services through powershell I am able to get IP restriction for webappname.azurewebsites.net but
I want to fetch IP restriction for the kudu console or SCM website as well is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61018124/to-get-the-restricted-ips-for-webapp-in-azure-powershell) to `$WebAppConfig.Properties.scmIpSecurityRestrictions` to show all SCM sites IP restrictions in your subscription.

```
$APIVersion = ((Get-azResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Web).ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq sites).ApiVersions[0]
$WebApps = Get-azWebApp
    foreach ($webApp in $WebApps) {

        $WebAppName = $WebApp.Name
        $WebAppRGName = $webApp.ResourceGroup
        $WebAppConfig = (Get-azResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName  $WebAppName -ResourceGroupName $WebAppRGName -ApiVersion $APIVersion)
        $scmIpSecurityRestrictions = $WebAppConfig.Properties.scmIpSecurityRestrictions
        if ($scmIpSecurityRestrictions -eq $null) {
            Write-Host "No SCM site IP restrictions found for WebApp $WebAppName ."

        }
        else {
            Write-Host "SCM site IP restrictions set for WebApp $WebAppName : "
            $scmIpSecurityRestrictions

        }
    }
```